# How change "MediaLinkPrefix" Programmatically in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I know "MediaLinkPrefix" can be changed in web.config. But is it possible to change "MediaLinkPrefix" Programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question. No. You cannot programmatically change the value of that setting.

If you are trying to use `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem)` to get the URL of a `MediaItem` then that is leveraging the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider`, which pulls the value of the `MediaLinkPrefix`from the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaConfig` class. That property does not have a 'setter'. Furthermore, the value of that property actually comes from `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Media.MediaLinkPrefix`, which also doesn't have a setter and is pulled directly from the config file.

The `MediaManager` is a static class that I believe isn't able to be swapped out with a custom implementation. And, unlike the `LinkManager`, the `MediaManager` is hard coded to use the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider` so you can't write a custom provider either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating your own implementation of `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` and set it up in your web.config under the `<linkManager>` section.

I don't know the exact implementation, but you can inherit a class from `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` and then override the GetItemUrl() method.
Then configure your class to be used as LinkManager.